# How to stop an animation in the middle smoothly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The `curve` parameter in CurvedAnimation defines the animation curve for the whole duration of the animation.
Let us assume I have an animation which is throwing values form `0.0` to `360.0`. If I want to stop the animation somewhere in the middle, like when the value is 200 let's say, the animation stops suddenly, there's no role of the curve we had defined earlier, and rightly so. How can I make this stop happen smoothly? Same goes with resuming from this stopped position.

Comment: so you are trying to stop when the value is `200` but what should be the final value? i mean what should be the target value when animation speed is zero?

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean by target value?

Comment: your value goes like: 0, 50, 100, 150, 200 and when it is 200 you want to stop it, but not suddenly, so it cannot stop at 200 and my question is what should be that target value?

Comment: 200 is the target value, so maybe from 180 it starts to slow down gradually.

Comment: call `controller.stop()` followed by `controller.animateWith()` with `FrictionSimulation`